# How to delete the next n rows in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

How could I delete all the rows after the 20th in sqlite, in another way I need to maintain a  database with only 20 rows at each new insert I need to delete the oldest row inserted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM stuff
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
SELECT rowid FROM stuff ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 20);
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a3e2f/9